# How does Mold Earth (5e spell / cantrip) interact with lava / magma?

Tags: dnd-5e

Jeremy Crawford & Stack Exchange agree: [Mold Earth works on any material that will shovel](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139836/what-counts-as-loose-earth-for-the-mold-earth-spell) - but does this apply to magically shovelling magma-lava (*'enchanted shovel'*)? [Mold Earth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mold-earth) requires *loose earth*: liquid is 'loose'... and the Earth's core is arguably 'earth', right?

Mere cantrips moving 5' cubes of lava seems more for Red Dragons or Fire Giants (not PCs). Players' counter argument: cooled magma-lava pounded into gravel &/or dust will *Mold* - as described on the tin.

*Repeated question:* Are there ANY rulings, tweets, UA or even old scribblings from Gary Gygax on toilet paper that might prevent lava-magma manipulation with *Mold Earth*?

Comment: The answers in that other question don't address magma/lava as a potential target for the spell.

Comment: @nick012000 That does not mean this is not a duplicate question. That question has been bountied. No need to reopen this.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov It does, because the answers to that question don't apply to this question.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov thanks Thomas! You win some you lose some. Still wonder if this spell works on lava though?

Comment: @TimmJimmGrimm My bad, I forgot to add the info to the bounty, feel free to add in comments to the dupe!